# Rails API - render JSON seems broken it keeps return HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I am new to build Rails API from scratch (only API not web app) so I can build iOS app to connect to API. What I have an issue on my Rails API project doesn't allow me to have return JSON results, it always return HTML. Any idea what is wrong? Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks!

What I want to have like this:

```
{"code":12,"title":"User doesn't exist","status":404}
```

This is what I got (it returns in red header in HTML page):

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Api::V1::UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=5
```

---

Take a look at my scripts:

**routes.rb** (require JSON format):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do 
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :entries, except: [:new, :edit]
      resources :users, except: [:new, :edit]
    end
  end

end
```

**../app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

      def show
        if User.exists?(params[:id])
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
          render json: @user
        else 
          render json: { code: 12, title: "User doesn't exist", status: 404 }, status: :not_found
      end 
 .
 .
 .
```

#### Note: It is very strange how this *show* method above acting weird. Part 1 is working well to return JSON results but Part 2 returns HTML instead JSON results.

Part 1: `render json: @user`

Part 2:  `render json: { code: 12, title: "User doesn't exist", status: 404 }, status: :not_found`

**../app/controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, with: :render_bad_request  
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved, :with => :access_denied

  def render_bad_request(e)
    render json: params, status: :bad_request
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `User.where(id: params[:id]).first` instead `User.exists?()`. Is the same query and it going to be cached by Active Record.

Also, i think that you `before_action` method is the guilty. Try with this

`protected 
def set_user
   @user ||= User.where(id: params[:id]).first
end
...`

And in your controller

`def show
        if @user.present?
          render json: @user
        else 
          render json: { code: 12, title: "User doesn't exist", status: 404 }, status: :not_found
      end`

Comment: I updated my posted. Please have a look at it again. Thanks!